# Can i use name of element in javascript even?

Tags: javascript

Can i use name of element in javascript even ?

for use `id="xxx"` , we use

```
$('#xxx').prop('readonly', true);
```

And for `class="xxx"` , we use

```
$('.xxx').prop('readonly', true);
```

I want to know can we use `name="xxx"` in javascript even ?

Comment: In the future, check http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ before asking new questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`attribute="value"`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector:

```
$('[name="xxx"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Use something like :

```
  $('[name="xxx"]').prop('readonly', true);
```